# Datatable.js - not able to display data

Tags: c#, jquery, json, datatable

I am not able to retrieve data in datatable using datatable.js. The Json response is a string but in the output I get every character of the string in each row rather that jst two entries.

Please help. Thanks in advance

```
function fillGrid() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'BehindCode/client.aspx/fillgrid',

        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: function () {

            $('#gridLoadingDiv').attr('style', 'display:block');
        },
        complete: function () {

            $('#gridLoadingDiv').attr('style', 'display:none');
        },
        data: "{}",

        success: function (data) {
            data = data.d;
            alert(data);

            $("#clientTable").DataTable({
                "searching": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "data": data,

                    "columns": [{
                    "title": "CLIENT NAME"
                }]
            });
        }
    });
}
```

C# code..from where data is being retreived..

```
[WebMethod]

    public static string fillgrid()
    {
        BehindCode_client client = new BehindCode_client();

        string strfetch = "SELECT CLIENT_NAME FROM k_client_master";

        string aadata = "";

        client.ds = client.DEngine.GetDataSet(strfetch, "Data", client.conn);

        if (client.ds != null && client.ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
             aadata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(client.ds);
         //  aadata = "{'draw':1, 'recordsTotal':2, 'recordsFiltered':2, 'data':[{'CLIENT_NAME': 'Pyrotech'},{'CLIENT_NAME':'Workspace'}]}";  // tried this also
         //  aadata = "{'data':[{'CLIENT_NAME': 'Pyrotech'}, {'CLIENT_NAME':'Workspace'}]}";   // tried this as well
        }
            return (aadata.Replace("'","\""));
    }
}
```

---

JSON Response as in developer tools
[image: JSON Response which i got in designer view]

---

Output in datatable
[image: Output Table.. It is not showing "pyrotech' and "workspace" but evry character in every row.]

---

enteries in database which are retreived

[image: The enteries in the database from where the datatable is to be filled.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C# but on the JavaScript part you're not decoding the JSON data.

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data.d).Data;
    alert(data);

    $("#clientTable").DataTable({
        "searching": true,
        "processing": true,
        "data": data,

        "columns": [
            {data: "CLIENT_NAME"}
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: tried this.. it alerts "object Object" and dataTable shows "No data available in table"

Comment: Answer updated, try again. Your data array is contained in the Data attribute. This call was missing.

Comment: alerts two objects " object Object, object Object" and another error.."DataTables warning: table id=clientTable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4" and the table is empty.

Comment: Your datatable was misconfigured too. I updated my answer. See http://www.datatables.net/manual/data for configuration examples.